# insert, delete and update in C# using database?

Tags: c#

This program i wrote for insert,update

using dataset from C# database name is info can anyone check this code tharouly please help e what should i write over the syntax.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Insert_update_delete
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader dr;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            Loadlist();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtId.Text != "" & txtName.Text != "")
            {
                cn.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "Insert into info (Id, Name) Values('"+txtId.Text+"' , '"+txtName.Text+"')";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();(it is showing error here )
                cmd.Clone();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted!");
                cn.Close();
                txtId.Text = "";
                txtName.Text = "";
                Loadlist();
            }
        }
        private void Loadlist()
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            listBox2.Items.Clear();
            cn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * From info";
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                    listBox2.Items.Add(dr[1].ToString());
                }
            }

            cn.Close();
        }

        private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox l = sender as ListBox;
            if(l.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                listBox1.SelectedIndex = l.SelectedIndex;
                listBox2.SelectedIndex = l.SelectedIndex;
                txtId.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                txtName.Text = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtId.Text != "" & txtName.Text != "")
            {
                cn.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "Delete from info where id*'"+txtId.Text+"' and name*'"+txtName.Text+"'";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted");
                Loadlist();
                txtId.Text = "";
                txtName.Text = "";

            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtId.Text != "" & txtName.Text != "" & listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                cn.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "Update info set id='"+txtId.Text+"', name='"+txtName.Text+"' where id='"+listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()+"' and name= '"+listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()+"'";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Updated");
                Loadlist();
                txtId.Text = "";
                txtName.Text = "";

            }
        }
    }
}
```

no doubt on this one works fine please check.

Comment: "please help what is the error" - you're the one getting the error; you should tell *us* what the error is... then we can help you fix it. (Aside from anything else, you should look up SQL injection attacks, and change your code to use parameterized queries...)

Comment: Your sql is just flat out wrong... Arguably using this raw sql in your code has it's own problems (and lots of them), but running with your concept you should likely start by getting your sql right in a sql management program and then copy it into c#

Comment: in to should be one word into. Also LINQ is so much cleaner IMHO

Answer (score 4):

Remove space from insert statement. You have put space between `in to` which should be `into` so change your command Text like this.

```
   cmd.CommandText = "Insert into info (Id, Name) Values('"+txtId.Text+"' , '"+txtName.Text+"')";
```

one more this what is `*` in your delete statement. I think it will also cause a problem you when you pass over the current error

```
cmd.CommandText = "Delete from info where id*'"+txtId.Text+"' and name*'"+txtName.Text+"'";
```

So it should

```
cmd.CommandText = "Delete from info where id=" + txtId.Text+"' and name='"+txtName.Text+"'";
```

Now Your Update Command : Here you have missed `,` between multiple columns. Your update command should be like this

```
cmd.CommandText = "Update info set id='"+txtId.Text+"', name='"+txtName.Text+"' where id='"+listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()+"' and name= '"+listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()+"'";
```

Comment: Hi Sachin in the same code button3 i am getting same error on update

Comment: @Mohan I have update my answer for Update command.

Comment: So I hope now you have working code, and one more thing as it is your first question on SO, So i would like to know you that if particular answer has helped you then you can accept that as answer by cheking the checked option available there :)

Answer (score 3):

This SQL is not valid SQL:

```
"Delete from info where id'"+txtId.Text+"' and name'"+txtName.Text+"'";
"Insert in to info (Id, Name) Values('"+txtId.Text+"' , '"+txtName.Text+"')";
"Update info set id='"+txtId.Text+"'name='"+txtName.Text+"' where id='"+listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()+"' and name= '"+listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()+"'";
```

It should:

1. Contain `=` signs when making comparisons in the DELETE, instead of the `*`.
2. Use `into` and not `in to` in the INSERT.
3. Have commas between fields in the UPDATE.
4. Should not be concatenating the SQL, but use parameterized queries.

The only valid SQL you have there is the SELECT. You should try running your queries in SQL Server Management Studio before you write them in the program.

Comment: Although the select is valid, it is suspect. I've added an additional answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess it's that you're using "Insert in to info" when you should be using "INSERT INTO info".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your insert command has an typo in it:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Insert in to info (Id, Name) Values('"+txtId.Text+"' , '"+txtName.Text+"')"
```

should be something like:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Insert into info (Id, Name) Values('"+txtId.Text+"' , '"+txtName.Text+"')"
```

Answer (score 0):

BEST PRACTICE

Don't use Select *.  Here you are only looking for 2 columns of data.  So, only select 2 colunms.  What if the table had 20 columns?  That's 18 extra column of data that were retrieved for nothing.  Also, refer to column names instead of indexes.  If someone in the future changes the schema of that table and inserts of column between columns 0 and 1, then your results may not be what is expected.

```
Select col1, col2 from info
```

Your code:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select * From info";
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                    listBox2.Items.Add(dr[1].ToString());
                }
            }
```

Comment: This will makes so many round trips to the database compared to a single `UPDATE table SET field = value` in SQL...