# Can't update SQL from WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

In my WPF (C#) application I am trying to update my SQL database when changes are made to a datagrid in the app.
Displaying the dataset in the Datagrid works fine, but I can not get updates made in the datagrid sent back to the database.

This is what I have so far - The issue is, that I can't figure out how to pass the dataset (ds) and the sqladapter (sea) to the BtnSave_Click void, which should update the SQL with the changes made (I get a "Mainwindow does not contain a definition for 'ds'). I have been using VB.Net previously and there I could declare them as public variables, but that can't be done here I guess. I have read that I could declare a static class and put them there, but also that that is a bad technique.
I am very thankful for any suggestions on how to proceed. Cheers, Peter.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       
    }
    
    private void grdSchedule_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        
        string strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["strCon"].ConnectionString;
        string CmdString = string.Empty;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strCon))
        {
            CmdString = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Schedule";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sda.TableMappings.Add("Table", "tbl_Schedule");
            DataSet ds = new DataSet("tbl_Schedule");
            sda.Fill(ds, "tbl_Schedule");
            grdSchedule.ItemsSource =ds.Tables["tbl_Schedule"].DefaultView;
            ds.AcceptChanges();
        }
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet changes = this.ds.GetChanges();
        if (changes != null)
        {
            //Data has changes. 
            //use update method in the adapter. it should update the datasource
            int updatedRows = this.sda.Update(changes);
            this.ds.AcceptChanges();
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578758/insert-delete-and-update-in-c-sharp-using-database and [How to: Update Rows in the Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/how-to-update-rows-in-the-database)

Answer (score 1):

For save changes via sqlDataAdapter you need to specify commands for properties [UpdateCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.updatecommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0), [DeleteCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.deletecommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0), [InsertCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.insertcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0).

Also need notice that such commands must contains parameters which will be binded to columns in your DataTable.

```
var updateCommand = new SqlCommand("Update tbl_schedule set OperationId=@OperationId where Id=@Id")
updateCommand.Parameters.Add("@OperationId", SqlDbType.int, "OperationId")
updateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int, "Id");
sda.UpdateCommand = updateComand;
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for that. I was just reading up on the same thing in another thread. I will fix this right away. But the questlon of how to pass the adapter and dataset to the btn_Save void still remains?

Comment: I can't see a problem here -> you can use fields in your form for sqlDataAdapter and DataSet or better define class AppContext - which will be responsible for manage your data (it is more better from testing purposes)... and consume instance of this type in your form.